# Smack send and receive message without chat

Tags: java, smack

I would like to send a simple message from one client to another one not opening a chat because there will never be a response and all messages fire the same event.

In the smack (4.1.7) documentation I found out that it is possible to do so but so far I did not find a way how to do it.

Do you have any ideas how to do it?
Would it be better (especially acording to performance: runtime and memory) to use the chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For receiving you'd probably want to use a synchronous stanza listener with a suitable filter.For example, if you want to receive messages with a body from user@example.org, then you could

```java
XMPPConnection connection = …;
connection.addSyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {

@Override
void process(Stanza stanza) {
    Message message = (Message) stanza;
    // Received new message with body from user@example.org
}, new AndFilter(MessageWithBodiesFilter.INSTANCE, 
    FromMatchesFilter.create("user@example.org")));
```

Sending messages is even easier

```
Message message = new Message("user@example.org", "Hi, how are you?");
XMPPConnection connection = …;
connection.sendStanza(message);
```

**Hint: Reading the source code of Smack is a great way to learn about such stuff. If you look at the [source of ChatManager](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/5c00172f6a8d6c5f7e39f47badf1ac30fd25bccd/smack-im/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/chat/ChatManager.java), you will find what I've just written above.**